# Test web site validity in Java

Tags: java, http, url, httpurlconnection, keystore

I am writing a program in java that tests the validity of many websites. My plan is to get the URL, append http on the front and use HttpURLConnection class.

My problem is that I sometimes get 403 forbidden for the response code. Is there any way around this? If I get a 403 forbidden would that mean that the website is indeed valid? I've pasted the URL with a 403 code into the browser and was able to connect just fine.

Another problem is that I often get 301, 302, and 303 which I know are related to redirects. I then get the redirect url from the "Location" key in the head. When connecting to these I then get an error related to certificate chaining. I believe this can be solved by using a KeyStore that contains a list of certificates or certificate issuers that we deem valid. Does that sound right?

Thanks.

I don't have my code on this PC but I will try to recreate it.

```
pingSuccess = false;

HttpUrlConnection connection = (HttpUrlConnection) new URL(urlString).openConnection();
int response = connection.getResponseCode();

if(response == 301 || response == 302 || response == 303) {
    String newUrl = connection.getHeaderSomething("Location");
    connection = (HttpUrlConnection) new URL(newUrl).openConnection();
    response = connection.getResponseCode();

    if(response == 200) 
        pingSuccess = true;

}

return pingSuccess;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was googling around and found this. I set this on the connection and I am able to get a 200 response (good) for a website that was previously giving a 403, even though accessing the website in a browser was fine.

```
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36");
```

Answer (score 0):

**403 - Forbidden Access**

This indicates a fundamental access problem, which may be difficult to resolve because the HTTP protocol allows the Web server to give this response without providing any reason at all. So the 403 error is equivalent to a blanket 'NO' by the Web server - with no further discussion allowed.

By far the most common reason for this error is that directory browsing is forbidden for the Web site. Most Web sites want you to navigate using the URLs in the Web pages for that site. They do not often allow you to browse the file directory structure of the site. For example try the following URL (then hit the 'Back' button in your browser to return to this page):

http://www.browsesites.com/accounts/B1394343/

This URL should fail with a 403 error saying "Forbidden: You don not have permission to access /accounts/B1394343/ on this server". This is because our browsesites Web site deliberately does not want you to browse directories - you have to navigate from one specific Web page to another using the hyperlinks in those Web pages. This is true for most Web sites on the Internet - their Web server has "Allow directory browsing" set OFF.

You first need to confirm if you have encountered a "No directory browsing" problem. You can see this if the URL ends in a slash '/' rather than the name of a specific Web page (e.g. .htm or .html). If this is your problem, then you have no option but to access individual Web pages for that Web site directly.

Tried your code with few minor edits. Posting the code:

```
package general;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class HTTPLinkTest {

public static boolean testLink(String urlLink){
    boolean pingSuccess = false;

    try {
        System.out.println("Test validity of URL:" + urlLink);
        URL myUrl = new URL(urlLink);
        HttpURLConnection connection;

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();

        int response = connection.getResponseCode();

        if(response == 301 || response == 302 || response == 303) {
            String newUrl = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
            System.out.println("Got redirected to new URL:" + newUrl);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(newUrl).openConnection();
            response = connection.getResponseCode();
            // Request has succeeded
            if(response == 200) 
                pingSuccess = true;

        }
    }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return pingSuccess;
}

public static boolean testSSLConnection(String sslLink){
    try {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        String host = sslLink;
        int port = 443;
        System.out.println("Creating secure socket to " + host + ":" + port);

        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, port);
        String[] suites = socket.getSupportedCipherSuites();
        System.out.println("Supported suites are:");
        for (String suite : suites){
            System.out.println(suite);
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] sslLinks = {"netbanking.hdfcbank.com"};
    for (String sslLink: sslLinks){
        testSSLConnection(sslLink); 
    }

    String[] links = {"http://www.yahoo.com" , "http://www.yahoo.com/book"};
    for (String link : links){
        System.out.println("Test Result: " + link + (testLink(link) ? " is Valid URL":" is Invalid URL"));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

> Output:
>     Creating secure socket to netbanking.hdfcbank.com:443
>
> Supported suites are:
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>   TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>   TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>   SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>   SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>   SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
>   TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>   TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>   SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>   SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
>   SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
>   SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
>   SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
>   SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
>   SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
>   SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
>   SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
>   TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
>   SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
>   TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
>   TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
>   TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA
>   SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
>   TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5
>   TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
>   TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5
>   TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA
>   TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5
>   Test validity of URL:http://www.yahoo.com
>   Got redirected to new URL:https://www.yahoo.com/

Comment: regarding your SSL/TLS query, can you share your code/snippet with output.

Comment: But what about when I get a 403 when checking the response code in Java but when I access the website in a browser it works fine? The URL I'm checking does not have a '/' at the end. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the noob question but are you guy asking me for my code snippet? Your comments show up under DROY's response and not under mine. I will post mine anyways. lol I'm guessing DROY wouldn't ask his own code snippet...

Comment: What is a supported cipher suite? So when it connects to port 443 of the website with the SSLSocket what is it checking? Does it pretty much not give an exception if http response is between 200 and 399? I know i doesn't actually give an http response but internally what does it do?

Comment: I don't have the link with me as it is at work. Sorry.

Comment: Give it a try and let me know. We can improve the solution accordingly.

Comment: Regarding your question on what is getSupportedCipherSuites(), it will return the names of cipher suites which could be enabled for use on an SSL connection.